# what is the fair partnership split in property flipping between the investor and the contractor?

Tags: real-estate, contractor, investment-property

My potential business partner just bought a foreclosure property and asked me to fix it up and sell it. Obviously he is just spending the money but I am doing all the work under my own LLC like being an architect, contractor and doing all the leg work like pulling the permits and all the documentation.

Now the question that we gonna decide on tomorrow is that what is the fair partnership in this situation?

I am not making any profit on contracting, and he is the one writing check and money is not the issue for him (like it doesn’t matter if i use my money to fix up the property). Is 50/50 too much to ask or 30/70? Me being 30.

Comment: *Must* you be a partner?  Why not estimate the cost, add your profit, and tell him you'll do it for that price?  With half up front, of course, and a mechanics lien if he doesn't pay.

Comment: This can not be objectively answered. What is fair depends on what the parties involved THINK is fair.

Comment: What percentage of the total _value_  does each of you bring to the table, including intangible value such as industry reputation along with cash, hours, and other more easily measured resources? This is not an easy question to negotiate agreement upon, but it's one way to establish a specific "fair" division of ownership. Otherwise, what's fair is whatever the parties involved agree upon, with the understand that both have to be satisfied or the deal doesn't get made.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do research to see what other flippers are doing regarding splinting the profits between the money people and the general contractor, which is what you are.

Every partnership is different, as is the division of responsibilities.

What is interesting is that you called them a potential partner, yet they have already bought a foreclosed property. That means they have purchased a property, and by this time they should have done a structural analysis, made a plan, costed the plan, and estimated the sales price; so they can determine an estimated profit. If all that has been done, then your tasks and responsibilities are reduced.

You will also need to know what risks you have if the profits are smaller, or there are no profits because the foundation needed 50K in unexpected repairs.